# EC2 User-data script being completely ignored

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I took the userdata for the ElasticBeanstalk AMI to try and add some stuff of my own. Should be easy.

Specially because there is already a session in the userdata where some shell script is run. So I put my stuff there and it gets completely ignored. It doesn't run, it doesn't log anything, it produces exactly zero results.

Anyone knows why?

This is the original user-data:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============5189065377222898407=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============5189065377222898407==
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
repo_upgrade: none
repo_releasever: 2017.09
cloud_final_modules:
 - [scripts-user, always]

--===============5189065377222898407==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="user-data.txt"

#!/bin/bash
exec > >(tee -a /var/log/eb-cfn-init.log|logger -t [eb-cfn-init] -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1
echo [`date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`] Started EB User Data
set -x


function sleep_delay 
{
  if (( $SLEEP_TIME < $SLEEP_TIME_MAX )); then 
    echo Sleeping $SLEEP_TIME
    sleep $SLEEP_TIME  
    SLEEP_TIME=$(($SLEEP_TIME * 2)) 
  else 
    echo Sleeping $SLEEP_TIME_MAX  
    sleep $SLEEP_TIME_MAX  
  fi
}

# Executing bootstrap script
SLEEP_TIME=10
SLEEP_TIME_MAX=3600
while true; do 
  curl https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-west-2/stalks/eb_node_js_4.0.1.143.7/lib/UserDataScript.sh > /tmp/ebbootstrap.sh 
  RESULT=$?
  if [[ "$RESULT" -ne 0 ]]; then 
    sleep_delay 
  else
    /bin/bash /tmp/ebbootstrap.sh     'https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-west-2/stalks/eb_node_js_4.0.1.143.7/lib/aws-elasticbeanstalk-tools-1.20-1.noarch.rpm'    'https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-west-2/stalks/eb_node_js_4.0.1.143.7/lib/awseb-ruby-2.2.4-x86_64-20160503_1008.tar.gz https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-west-2/stalks/eb_node_js_4.0.1.143.7/lib/basehooks.tar.gz'    'https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-west-2/stalks/eb_node_js_4.0.1.143.7/lib/beanstalk-core-2.11.gem https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-west-2/stalks/eb_node_js_4.0.1.143.7/lib/beanstalk-core-healthd-1.1.gem https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-env-resources-us-west-2/stalks/eb_node_js_4.0.1.143.7/lib/executor-1.2.gem'    'https://cloudformation-waitcondition-us-west-2.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-west-2%3A731735707548%3Astack/awseb-e-qprmcmyjbp-stack/261dc900-e722-11e7-bcbb-503ac9ec2461/AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitHandle?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIY5RM4DUXMU25KNA&Expires=1514038355&Signature=Nha6e4UQYJLWCOjxnj7nHXYzFDY%3D'    'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:731735707548:stack/awseb-e-qprmcmyjbp-stack/261dc900-e722-11e7-bcbb-503ac9ec2461'    'us-west-2'    '30755f954950'    'e9af7960-20f2-46da-9353-a69cb7dedeff'    ''    'nginx'    ''    && 
    exit 0  
  fi 
done

--===============5189065377222898407==-- ##Ec2InstanceReplacementRequest=7577e7d0-ebe5-11e7-bd10-6bec9097cbda
```

I'm trying to add this series of commands to it:

```
aws s3 cp s3://oidevops/beanstalk/application-configs/chatbot-admin/dev/91_install_cloudwatchlogs_agent.sh .
aws s3 cp s3://oidevops/beanstalk/application-configs/chatbot-admin/dev/91_awslogs_restart.sh .
chmod 750 91install_cloudwatchlogs_agent.sh && chmod 750 91_awslogs_restart.sh
cp 91_install_cloudwatchlogs_agent.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post
cp 91_awslogs_restart.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/restartappserver/post
cp 91_awslogs_restart.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post
```

So I placed them at the end of the `Content-Type: text/x-shellscript;` section of this multipart. Tried at the beggining too, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

User Data on Linux servers must have `#!` on the first line, otherwise it is not executed as a script.

If you wish to add software to an Elastic Beanstalk environment, you should use `.ebextensions`.

See: [Advanced Environment Customization with Configuration Files (.ebextensions) - AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html)

Comment: Customizing via ebextensions is not really practical as I depend on developers to do it.
As I said in my question, I placed my code on a section that begins with `#!/bin/bash` and still it doesn't run.

Comment: If the _very first line_ does not contain `#!`, then the User Data will _not_ be run as a script. There's a lot of strange MIME stuff in ^ listing!

Comment: The MIME allows to use multiple different files or configs to launch the instance in the cloud. It uses `cloud-init` under the hood. The section talking about `userdata.txt` is indeed the content of the file that gets taken as `UserData` and it does indeed start with `#!`.

Comment: @ChristianDechery Did you ever end up solving this issue? I am trying to modify the UserData of my Single Instance Elastic Beanstalk environment-type, but I can't seem to figure out how.